# How to configure log4j with Spring Framework with different configuration files

Tags: java, spring, log4j

How can I configure spring framework 5 using different configuration files, either using profiles or code, some idea where I can see an example, thanks

my pom file

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    example.example1
    example
    war
    1.0
    example
    http://www.example.com
    
        UTF-8
        5.0.7.RELEASE
        4.2.8.RELEASE
        2.0.0.RELEASE
        2.3.4.RELEASE
        2.0.8.RELEASE
        5.2.16.Final
        /
        1.8
        1.8
        yyMMdd.HH.mm
        ${maven.build.timestamp}

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>stagein</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <resources.path>resources/stagein</resources.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <resources.path>resources/prod</resources.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>


<dependencies>
    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet -->

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring -->

    <!-- Spring Cloud -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.cloud.aws.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.cloud.aws.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Cloud -->

    <!-- Spring Data JPA -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.jpa}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-sql-spring</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data JPA -->

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security -->

    <!-- Spring Security OAuth2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.oauth2.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security OAuth2 -->

    <!-- Mysql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mysql -->

    <!-- Jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jackson -->

    <!-- JsonView -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.monitorjbl</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-json-view</artifactId>
        <version>0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JsonView -->

    <!-- Lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.8</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Lombok -->

    <!-- Log -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Log -->

    <!-- Commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Commons -->

    <!-- Amazon AWS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.336</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.336</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.255</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Amazon AWS -->

    <!-- Java Mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Java Mail -->

    <!-- Cache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Cache -->

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->

    <!-- Apache POI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ZipUtils -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
        <artifactId>zt-zip</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jasperreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- web-sockets -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlgraphics/xmlgraphics-commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlgraphics-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HTML to plain text -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>example</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <warName>${project.build.finalName}-${timestamp}</warName>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/views</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/home.jsp</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>       
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your Spring Framework uses more than one configuration files shouldn't affect the log4j configuration.
Just add the log4j dependency in your build tool (Maven/Gradle) and create a `resources/log4j.configuration` file which specifies all the desired log4j configuration.

If you wish to have the ability to override the log4j configurations depending on a `profile`, you'll need to create dedicated log4j.properties file per profile and specify it in the profile section of your build tool.
The following code snippet it's a Maven pom.xml profile section:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <resources.path>resources/dev</resources.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <resources.path>resources/prod</resources.path>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

In the above example, you'll have 2 different log4j.properties located as follows:
`resources/prod/log4j.properties` and `resources/dev/log4j.properties` which will be used by `dev` and `prod` profiles separately.

Comment: Itzik Shachar thanks for response. I try to run your example in my proyect but doesn`t work, iam not using spring boot any idea

Comment: i can overwrite a variable for read a differrent configuration file?
or maven profiles only works for compilation time? i run my proyecto on eclipse and tomcat

Comment: In case you are working with a build tool like `Maven` or `Gradle`, please provide it's configuration file and I'll instruct you on how to set it's profile section.

Comment: i added my pom file